# What are the best options for data loading in bigger systems? (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, datatables

as my question says, I would like to know what is my best choice for loading data in bigger systems in Laravel.

At the moment I use **Laravel Eloquent** to pull data from database and in my views I use **dataTables** JS library. It is effective for smaller systems or websites. However I seem to find myself in a position where systems that are bigger and more complex take very long time to load those data (sometimes more than 15 seconds).

I have found some solutions:

- **Eager loading** relations helps with relations in row
- Using **DB** instead of Eloquent
- using Laravel **pagination** instead of dataTables pagination
- loading data to dataTables from **ajax** source

However the pagination has some problems, especially with dataTables having the option of ordering/searching data.

My question is do you have any advice on how to load data in most effective way, so that it is as fast as it could be and the code as clean as possible. What do you do, when you need to load ginormous amount of data?

Comment: Hi if you are using datatables than use ajax to load data that will make your table fast, some operations which you can perform at sql level do there like sum, count don't use Eloquent for this. without ajax datatables take time to process all rows and js operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On of the best ways to optimize your queries is by using [MySQL indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html). As per this documentation:

> Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read
> through the entire table to find the relevant rows. The larger the
> table, the more this costs. If the table has an index for the columns
> in question, MySQL can quickly determine the position to seek to in
> the middle of the data file without having to look at all the data.
> This is much faster than reading every row sequentially.

The most simple way to create an index is the following:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column1, column2, ...);
```

If you want the Laravel way of creating index, you can do it by using  `index()` method, as per official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#indexes):

```
$table->index('column');
```